# binary tree - to check if it is height-balanced

Tags: java, binary-tree

I have a sample code from [GeeksforGeeks](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-determine-if-a-binary-tree-is-balanced/).

It says that the first solution is O(N<sup>2</sup>) on a skewed tree.

I have a tree like this.

```
    3
     \
      4
       \
        6
         \
          7
           \
            8
             \
              10
```

But when I walk through the code, it seems like O(N). It just recursively calls `height(node.right);`.

Can somebody correct me when it is O(N<sup>2</sup>)?

Thanks.

Comment: As in the exchange on current answer, for a worst case of O(N^2), the sample can be a full binary tree plus a leaf node or remove a leaf node from a full balance binary tree.

Answer (score 1):

Did you notice the `int height(struct node* node)` function ? For every node starting from root, the `bool isBalanced(struct node *root)` function calls the `int height(struct node* node)`.

Straightly, `bool isBalanced(struct node *root)` function visits all the nodes (in worst case) in the tree and each time it calls the `int height(struct node* node)` function(in worst case{`skewed tree`} it executes n times). Hence, the complexity is `O(N*N) = O(N^2)`.

Moreover, `int height(struct node* node)` function visits all of its child node, hence it needs to visit all of its child node(in worst case{`skewed tree`} `n`).

Comment: I added log into height() method and it only prints one visit to each node, given a skewed tree as left.left.left.left.left. Would you please explain about the "Hence" between "executes n times" to "O(N^2)"?
```
int height(Node node)
    {
        /* base case tree is empty */
        if (node == null)
            return 0;

        System.out.println("visiting " + node.data);

        /* If tree is not empty then height = 1 + max of left
         height and right heights */
        return 1 + Math.max(height(node.left), height(node.right));
    }
```

Comment: @maxwu, I have said that `height()` function executes n times(in worst case) for each time the `isBalanced()` method calls. And clearly in worst case `isBalanced()` methods is called n times. So O(n*n) is the total complexity.

Comment: thank you. I thought about O(N^2) but made a log in linear. Now I got the reason. The worst case is not binary tree which degrades to linear form like in the question. It is an almost balance tree with 2^k node as a full binary tree plus one additional leaf-node on bottom.